# function to remove empty elements from array until a non-empty element is found

Tags: php

Assume I have an array like such:

```
$arr = array(0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => 'abc', 3 => '', 4 => '', 5 => 'def', 6 => '');
```

I want a function that will remove the empty values from array until it hits ANY non-empty value. So in this example, the result would be:

```
array(0 => 'abc', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => 'def', 4 => '');
```

I can create my own function but the question is.. does PHP already have something that accomplishes this? Is there an easy way to do this to use as little resources as possible?

index association is not important. in fact, i prefer that it resets

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who wants a little extension of PHP's array functionality here are 2 additional functions that I found useful.

```
/**
 * @abstract Removes empty elements from the left side of the array until it hits a value.
 * @param array $array The array.
 * @return array|boolean Returns the modified array on success, otherwise false.
 */
function array_filter_left($array) {
    if (!is_array($array))
        return false;
    while ($array && !$array[0])
        array_shift($array);
    return $array;
}

/**
 * @abstract Removes empty elements from the right side of the array until it hits a value.
 * @param array $array The array.
 * @return array|boolean Returns the modified array on success, otherwise false.
 */
function array_filter_right($array) {
    if (!is_array($array))
        return false;
    while ($array && !$array[sizeof($array) - 1])
        array_pop($array);
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```
while($arr && !$arr[0]) array_shift($arr);
```

There is no built-in function to do this.

Comment: actually, you are using built-in functions here :)

Comment: @mark But there is no *single* function to do it, I had to use a loop.

Comment: It still doesn't get much longer and any "single" function would just do the same internally^^ So no point in trying, anyway.

Comment: i added 2 functions that accomplish just that.. from left side, and right side. id much rather use the function than retype this every time..